# How to add default active class on page load in angular 2+

Tags: angular

```
<ul>
    <li routerLinkActive = "active" class = "" >
    <a routerLink = "/A" skipLocationChange > A < /a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive = "active" class = "" >
    <a routerLink = "/B" skipLocationChange > B < /a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive = "active" class = "" >
    <a routerLink = "/C" skipLocationChange > c < /a>
    </li>
```

My routing.ts

{
    path: '',
    component: A,
    pathMatch: 'full'
}, {
    path: 'A',
    component: A
}, {
    path: 'B',
    component: B,
}, {
    path: 'B',
    component: B
}, {
    path: 'C',
    component: C
}, {
    path: '**',
    component: A
}

I want as the page load my A  component should come which is coming but the active is not coming on li on the page load i active class should come on li and as i move to another tab than the active class shall toggle depending on the component we are in.. plz help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your navigation component, import ActivatedRoute and have your 'active' class compare to the route that the user is currently on.

```
<li [ngClass]="{'active' : route == 'A'}"><a href="">A</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last route to

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'A' }
```